# Hide jQuery mobile "loading"-text - it is always visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

How can I hide this "loading"-text from jQuery mobile / AJAX? it is always visible

I've already tried

```
 $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
    $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
 })
```

but it doesn't work... can help me someone?

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXIGY.png)

Comment: Can you check if `$.mobile.loading` is what you expect it to be? Also, please use `.on` as `.bind` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a timer since the loader may have been loaded after any events have been fired. Or you could try the placement of the .hide() to be at the bottom of the body tag after the element is loaded into the DOM.

```
$(document).on('mobileinit',function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $("#some-element").hide(); 
    },1);
});
```

after DOM...

```
<script>
$("#some-element").hide();
<script>
</body>
```

etc...

Comment: idk what's the id from the "loading" text .. it will not display in the source code :/

Comment: oh.. yea .. it's `<div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default"><span class="ui-icon-loading"></span><h1>loading</h1></div>`

Comment: Excellent! Don't forget you can always use your Developer tools in the browser to interrogate the code and find any issue to your problem.

Comment: ty so much bro :)  I wouldn't have thought of it 

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function(){ 
      $(".ui-loader").hide(); 
   },10);
});
```

does work fine! :)

Comment: Excellent, I don't know how many times I have needed to use a SetTimeout to do something easy ;)